# why do I get error in rectangle() command in opencv even though my syntax is correct

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6da0b764e8c2> in <module>
----> 1 cv2.rectangle(blank_img,pt1=(384,0),pt2=(510,150),colour=(0,0,255),thickness=10)
      2 plt.imshow(blank_img)

TypeError: rectangle() missing required argument 'rec' (pos 2)
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: remove the variables from the function call. just put in the numbers like so. cv2.rectangle(image,(384,0),(510,150),(0,0,255),10)

Answer (score 0):

So your issues seems to be that you are using some random keyword arguments and it wont work like this.

For example:

```
def some_function(param1, param2):
    print(param1, param2)
```

Now calling this function will work both:

```
>>> some_function("value of param1", "value of param2")
value of param1 value of param2
```

or

```
>>> some_function(param1="value of param1", param2="value of param2")
value of param1 value of param2
```

or even

```
>>> some_function(param2="value of param2", param1="value of param1")
value of param1 value of param2
```

but using random parameter names wont work like:

```
      >>> some_function(newparam="new param",another_new_param="another new param")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: some_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'newparam'
```

Comment: The error you have reproduced is not the same as the OP shows.

Comment: Not exactly but the point stands. DONT use some random parameter names. I tested the OP-s cv2.rectangle with and without the param names. guess which one worked.

Comment: @quamrana the reason the error is not the same as the OP shows is because OpenCV isn't a Python library. It collects the arguments and passes them to C++ function calls, and the OP's error message is what you get in this instance. The "better" error message handled by Python makes more sense, but at least they're both `TypeError`s anyway.